# How to build Geometric network in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, geometric-network, trace, upstream

I have sample dataset of Water network. I wanted to make it geometrically connected network. I was trying to trace the network end to end, I have used "FnodeTnode tracing" plugin, but I was not lucky enough to achieve tracing. Do I need to change/ Add the Columns in the TAB files to make that plugin work? Is there any Extension that can help me in this? Is there any Mapbasic script that I can use to create the Geometric network connection and helps e to run the Upstream and downstream tracing?

Comment: Unfortunately, you probably won't find an answer online. Perhaps talk to your local MapInfo representative? Another question is, why are you limited to MapInfo. There may be another solution to your problem in another application?

Comment: @AlexLeith as far I checked, ArcGIS, Small world, Bently solution can solve the issue. But they will charge wholesome for the license. If it is Mapinfo, We can bare the price. If we have similar kind of solution available within any open source, I will be the most happiest person to know and use it ;) Please advice if you know any.

Comment: What are you trying to do, ultimately? You might be able to do some of the network analysis in PostGIS using their topology tools.

Comment: I want to Trace the Water network from Customer point to Pump house. In the network there are few other map features which should participate in the Network like Major Water Pipe lines, Minor water pipe lines, Valves, pumps and e.t.c.. If I should be able to Trace the network from Customer location or from the Pump house. If Start Tracing from Pumphouse, the entire Customer which are connected to that particular pump house including Major,minor,valves,pumps..e.t.c should gets selected / higlighted... this is my actual requirement. .. Please suggest some Workable plugin for this..

Comment: @BunnyChowdary Comments are for potential answerers to request more info or clarification.  Your response should be as an [edit] to the question, not as a further comment.  Other users shouldn't need to read through all the comments to get a complete picture of the problem or your desired outcome.  Please also be aware that if you are after solutions for other GIS packages (as suggested in one of your comments) that will put your question into the Too Broad category and likely be put On Hold.

Comment: Do you have MapInfo or are you looking at buying it if this is possible?  Have you contacted a MapInfo rep?  What did they say?